# how to interact go-rest-api & go-ipfs on the docker

Tags: docker, ipfs, go-fiber

docker-compose.yaml is like this

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  peer.hyperism.com:
  server.hyperism.com:

networks:
  hyperism_net:
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: ${PUBLIC_DATA_NETWORKS}

services:

  # MongoDB
  mongo_db:
    container_name: "mongo_db_container"
    image: mongo
    ports: 
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - ./mongodb:/data/db
    restart: always
    networks:
      - hyperism_net
  
  # Fiber
  fiber:
    env_file: .env
    build: .
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    environment:
      PORT: 3000
      MONGO_URI: mongodb://mongo_db:27017
      DB_NAME: my_db
    depends_on:
      - mongo_db
      - ipfs0
    restart: always
    networks:
      - hyperism_net
  
  ipfs0:
    container_name: ipfs0
    image: ipfs/go-ipfs:latest
    environment:
      PORT: 5001
    ports:
#     - "4001:4001" # ipfs swarm - expose if needed/wanted
      - 5001:5001 # ipfs api - expose if needed/wanted
      - 8080:8080 # ipfs gateway - expose if needed/wanted
    volumes:
      - ./compose/ipfs0:/data/ipfs
    networks:
      - hyperism_net
```

docker status is like this

[docker status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZUAe.png)

and when i post files with postman, nothing is added on the ipfs and nothing is returned

```
./test.txt 
{0xc000438660}

added 
16:31:53 | 200 |    13ms |       127.0.0.1 | POST    | /meta/upload
```

when i run fiber not on docker, on local host with go run main.go,
the code works well like this

```
./test.txt 
{0xc000438660}
QmPBp8SZSCm6r6yuhsRYhpr2AqGmFihA8r7foHsuHpqdBF
added QmPBp8SZSCm6r6yuhsRYhpr2AqGmFihA8r7foHsuHpqdBF
16:31:56 | 200 |    13ms |       127.0.0.1 | POST    | /meta/upload
```

upload function is like this

```
func Upload(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    sh := shell.NewShell("localhost:5001")

    file, err := c.FormFile("test")
    // c.SaveFile(file, fmt.Sprintf("./%s", file.Filename))
    
    fmt.Printf("./%s \n", file.Filename)
    
    f, _ := file.Open()
    cid, _ := sh.Add(bufio.NewReader(f))
    fmt.Println(f)
    fmt.Println(cid)
    fmt.Printf("added %s\n", cid)
    return err
}
```

i guess line

```
sh := shell.NewShell("localhost:5001")
```

should be modified.

what should i do?

Comment: The call to `localhost` is calling back into its own container.  Have you read background material like [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/), which describes how to connect between containers?

Comment: thanks i solved the problem